# Why can I call api port from React app using ip address, but not when I use "localhost"

Tags: reactjs, axios

React or axios do not seem to understand what local host is set to.

I'm serving a react client app on port 3000, and a react api server on port 3030.

I can call `curl -s localhost:3030` from command line and get a good reply.  But when I call using axios or fetch within my client app, I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

For example, this works:

```
axios.post("http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3030/authentication", {
```

This does not work (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED):

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3030/authentication", {
```

(Where localhost is the same machine with the xxx number above)

I don't think it's a CORS issue as I've tried setting the following headers in the server and sending them in post request.

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

Also, my browser seems to report CORs errors explicitly (at least, it has previously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are serving your client (React app) from a different port, and in 3030 it's only your backend, then it's probably CORS. You should configure your backend server to accept petitions from your app's domain.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a CORS issue.  I added some port details and headers part to the original question above to try and make it more clear.  But thanks for input.  Besides, I think that localhost should resolve to the same ip address -- so there is no cross-site issue, no?  Seems more like React or axios does not understand the value for localhost.